# SQLAlchemy simple query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to run the simplest query:

```
mysql> SELECT fullname,username,email FROM user;
```

---

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(60))
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

In SQLAlchemy notation. I have tried:

```
user = User.query(User.fullname,User.username,User.email)
```

but it doesn't seen to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.query` is equivalent to (or a *syntactic sugar* for) `session.query(User)`, which will return all columns of `User`. In order to retrieve only selected columns, use:

```
user = session.query(User.fullname, User.username, User.email)
```